# How are permissions enforced in IPC between apps?

Tags: android, permissions, ipc

I am new to Android and am having a hard time finding a good answer to the following question about permissions and IPC:

If App 1 has the permission to do something (lets say read contacts), but App 2 does not have this permission, can App 2 obtain the users contacts through IPC with App 1? Lets assume App 1 does not protect any of its activities/ect with permissions, but it still has the uses-permission for READ_CONTACTS.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Once the information is in app1 it can do whatever it wants with it. Including sending it to app2.  But there is no magic way to use IPC to get information out of any app.

Answer (score 1):

> If App 1 has the permission to do something (lets say read contacts), but App 2 does not have this permission, can App 2 obtain the users contacts through IPC with App 1?

If App 1 lets it, yes. This would be a security flaw in App 1, if App 1 does not take steps to ensure that App 2 has the proper permissions.